# How to add amazon affiliate Link in React Js website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-advertising-api

I tried to add amazon affiliate link in react application and it is not getting rendered.The code to be embedded is -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      var aax_size='728x90';
      var aax_pubname = 'abcde-200';
      var aax_src='302';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://c.amazon-adsystem.com/aax2/assoc.js"></script>
```

I tried to add the code in the following way

```
 const script = document.createElement('script')
 const script2 = document.createElement('script')

  script.type='text/javascript';
  script.lang='javascript'

  script.innerHTML="var aax_size='728x90'; var aax_pubname = 'abcde-200'; var aax_src='302';\n      \n"

  script2.type='text/javascript';
  script2.lang='javascript';
  script2.src='http://c.amazon-adsystem.com/aax2/assoc.js';
```

The ads are not showing up eventhough the scripts are rendered. PLease help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you append the script and script2 to the body?

```
document.body.appendChild(script);
document.body.appendChild(script2);
```